# Why is Webpack bundling all referenced libraries?

Tags: typescript, webpack, phaser-framework

In my project I have only one line in my entry TypeScript file:

```
// app.ts
import Phaser from 'phaser'
```

Phaser a is dependency which is located within my `node_modules` folder. My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map',

    entry: './src/app.ts',

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.js',
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

The strange thing is that the resulting file contains hundreds of lines of code. It looks like Webpack bundles the entire library. That shouldn't be the case, since I exclude the `node_modules` folder.

How can I get Webpack to stop doing this?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/? Otherwise, how does your bundle get access to Phaser in the users' browsers?

Comment: When you use something, you are using it and everything it uses, all the way down. Webpack will do its best to include only one version of any thing used and will only include referenced items where possibly, but if you use `Phaser`, you need all of the things it imports.

Comment: `phaser` has two dependencies, one of which has two dependencies, one of which has *six* dependencies, one of which has one, another has five, which in turn have their own, and so on, and so on, and so on.... Have you actually established that Webpack is including things that *aren't* in that dependency graph?

Answer (score 2):

Phaser 3 doesn't have tree shaking as far as I'm aware, so importing Phaser, is importing the entire Phaser library and everything that it depends on.
Webpack has no way of knowing that you haven't actually used it at all (and don't plan to at runtime)